# File copy permission denied while using shell_exec in php

Tags: php, tcl, permission-denied

I am running a `tcl` script from a `php` file as follows,

```
$cmd = "tclsh compare.tcl  $src $dst  2>&1";
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
echo $output;
```

In the tcl script, I am copying one file from one directory to other directory. When I ran the script from terminal, it is working fine. But, when triggered from `php`, I am getting the following error.

```
error copying "/somedir/summary.log" to "/anotherdir/summary.log": permission denied while executing "file copy -force $remote_file $local_file"
```

Comment: I guess you're "triggering from `php` by running through a web server of some kind. Are you running under the same user when you test the tcl script from the terminal?

Comment: Yes. I have LAMP server, through which any user can access it. When I ran the script via php, sometimes, I can see the output and sometimes not. (Not sure why). When I tried from some other's pc,they are also not able to get the output and found this issue. What I have to do make this available for all users in our group ?

Comment: I'm guessing that the web server user either doesn't have write permission to the target directory or read permission to the source file. A relatively common problem with web programming, unfortunately.